# i have an error in loading my view page shows error in codeigneter mvc

Tags: php, codeigniter

model/pages_m.php

```
function test()
 {
$this->load->database();
//$this->db->SELECT('*');
$q = $this->db->get("register");
//if($q->num_rows() > 0)
foreach ($q->result() as $row)
{
  return $q->result();
}
return array();
  }
```

controller/pages.php

```
 function test()  
 {
$this->load->model("pages_m");
$data['records'] = $this->pages_m->test();
$this->load->view("test",$data);
    }
```

view/test.php

```
<?php
  <table>
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Content</th>
</tr>
<?php
    foreach($records as $row):
?>
<tr>
    <td><?=$row->id?></td>
    <td><?=$row->name?></td>
    <td><?=$row->code?></td>
</tr>
<?php
    endforeach;
   ?>

 An Error Was Encountered
```

Unable to load the requested file: test.php
 this error is printing on screen.
 link is `localhost/codeigniter/index.php/pages/test`
as i am new to this frame work so i dont find the solution and its confusing me

Comment: Do you really think your local server link works for other users?

Comment: no i just posted this to show that am accessing the page through this url. is it a correct way?

Comment: ```foreach ($q->result() as $row)
{
  return $q->result();
}```. No need of foreach here, just return and check

Comment: and check if there is any typo-error in view file name

Comment: @kishor10d Unable to load the requested file: test.php this error is showing

Comment: please confirm once that your file is under view folder. and not any hierarchy of folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## This is how you could solve your view

In your view file, you have irreverent  for the php codes only. And what you have did in your view, you have write html table code within php tag.

```
view/test.php
<?php // remove this
<table>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>Title</th>
<th>Content</th>
</tr>
<?php
foreach($records as $row): //this is wrong ':', use '{' instead
?>
<tr>
<td><?=$row->id?></td> // write <?php not just <?
<td><?=$row->name?></td> // write <?php not just <?
<td><?=$row->code?></td> // write <?php not just <?

</tr>
<?php    //this block doesn't required 
endforeach;
?>
```

If, still you want to keep your html code in php you must have to echo it.
i.e.

```
<?php 
echo "<html> 
<body> 
<p>your html content </p>  
</body> 
</html>";
?>
```

Comment: Type: ParseError

Message: syntax error, unexpected '<', expecting end of file

Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\CodeIgniter\application\views\test.php

Line Number: 2 this is error printing

Comment: please refer the solution I gave to you and make necessary changes. specially where the html code is written and in the foreach loop.

Comment: @DwarkeshPurohit Nothing is wrong with [shorthand syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php).

Answer (score 0):

Add this code for your model

```
function test()
 {
   $this->load->database();
   //$this->db->SELECT('*');
   $q = $this->db->get("register");
   //if($q->num_rows() > 0)
   foreach ($q->result() as $row)
   {
     $data[] = $row['fieldValue'];
   }
   return $data;
  }
```

Comment: this error is showing   Type: Error

Message: Cannot use object of type stdClass as array

Comment: Its array problem so use $row->fieldValue;